# On sheet two I want to add a line using a yes no msgbox, when the line appears I want it to have text already

Tags: excel, vba

I need assistance with adding a line using a message box that will have text if added.  In the copy of the spreadsheet I want text in the description.  This is what I have so far but does not work!

```vb
Sub Add_1_Line()

If Worksheets("Sheet2") Then

Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult

    Answer = MsgBox("Do You Need To Insert An Amount From the Cabinet Template?", vbYesNo)

    If Answer = vbYes Then
      
         Worksheets("Insert Row").Rows(25).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
    End If
        
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest you change your header and text from "add a line" to "insert a row". Much more likely to get someone to look at this.

Comment: If asnwer is vbYes you want the macro insert a new row with text? which text ?